# Отображение чисел и строк в little endian

Tags: python, python-3.x, c, byte

Пытаюсь вывести представление чисел и строк в двоичном виде, но в обоих случаях при попытке разворота байтов и вывода в little endian результат не совпадает с ожидаемым. В случае с числами выводится тоже что и big endian. В случае со строками проверял на стороннем конвертере, но там в little endian выводится тоже самое что и в big.
В связи с чем дополнительный вопрос: нужно ли байты разворачивать при посимвольном представлении? Одинаково ли расшифруется такая двоичная строка в текстовую на компьютерах с big endian и с little endian?

```
        label_string = '12345'

        binary_string_big_endian = format(int(label_string), '>b')
        print('Число big endian : '+ binary_string_big_endian)
        binary_string_little_endian = format(int(label_string), '<b')
        print('Число little endian : '+ binary_string_little_endian)#not little

        binary_representation_big = ''.join(format(ord(char), '08b') for char in label_string)
        print('Cтрока big endian : '+binary_representation_big)# work

        binary_representation_little = ''.join(format(ord(char), '08b')[::-1] for char in label_string)
        print('Cтрока little endian : '+binary_representation_little)#not work
```

Вывод:

```
Число big endian : 11000000111001
Число little endian : 11000000111001
Cтрока big endian : 0011000100110010001100110011010000110101
Cтрока little endian : 1000110001001100110011000010110010101100
```

Answer (score 0):

`format` - не умеет учитывать эндианность. Он всегда выводит в "человеческом" представлении т.е.  big-endian, как принято записывать числа в тексте, независимо от разрядности системы счисления.

`>`, `<` - направления выравнивания текста. (Если длинна строкового представления числа меньше чем выделенное место, то будут добавлены пробелы слева или справа.) Например:

```
>>> format( 1233, '<10' )
'1233      '
>>> format( 1233, '>10' )
'      1233'
```

Если нужно little-endian представление, то проще всего переставить элементы строки в обратном порядке:

```
binary_string_little_endian = format(int(label_string), 'b')[::-1]
```